# run jasmine.js test as part of Maven 'test' goal

Tags: maven, jasmine

I have the following jasmine tests configuration in my project pom.xml:

```
<pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
              <goal>jasmine</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <jsSrcDir>${basedir}/src/main/js</jsSrcDir>
           <sourceIncludes>
            <include>myCode.js</include>
          </sourceIncludes>
          <jsTestSrcDir>${basedir}src/test/js/specs</jsTestSrcDir>
          <specIncludes>
            <include>mySpec.js</include>
          </specIncludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
...
```

with this configuraton I can run `jsamine:test` and the test wil run.

I want to run the tests as part of the goal `test`, but Maven won't run them.
I even tried removing the line `<goal>jasmine</goal>` but Maven still won't run the jasmine tests.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Is this is working for you? I am trying the same thing but no success :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must also add the execution of the plugin like this into you project:

```
<project>
  <build>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
          <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

cause the one you've defined in pluginManagement does not really execute the plugin.

Comment: thanks! it worked.
BTW - now maven says he can't execute the "jasmine" goal. removing the node `<goal>jasmine</goal>` solve it, but this means that I can't run only the jasmine tests. any idea?

Comment: You can use mvn jasmine:test as a goal instead of a life cycle.

Comment: It is not working for me, Did you changed somthing in goal??